# Cwd::abs_path returns backslash instead of forward slash

Tags: perl

```
abs_path("$FindBin::Bin/../../..");
```

returns

```
//jg/workspace/ns/v3/LINUX/full
```

Is there an easy way to get the path with other slash? I need

```
\\jg\workspace\ns\v3\LINUX\full
```

Comment: `$FindBin::RealBin` makes far more sense than `$FindBin::Bin` as it allows symlinks to your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File::Spec can normalize the path for you.

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
$path = canonpath($path);
```